# How do I specify which a tag I need when scraping in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup...

When I run this code:

```
inside_branding_info = container.div.find("div", "item-branding")
print(inside_branding_info)
```

It returns:

```
div class="item-branding">
<a class="item-rating" href="https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2060-super-gv-n206swf2oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932174?cm_sp=SearchSuccess-_-INFOCARD-_-graphics+cards-_-14-932-174-_-1&amp;Description=graphics+cards&amp;IsFeedbackTab=true#scrollFullInfo"><i class="rating rating-4"></i><span class="item-rating-num">(12)</span></a>
</div>
```

However, in the HTML inspection this is what I see: 
[Raw Site HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvJTT.png)

Everytime I run:
`inside_branding_info.a.img["title"]`
...python thinks I want the "a" tag "item-rating"...not the "a" href tag nested inside of the div "item-branding".

How do I get inside of the "a href" tag, then into the `"img"`, to finally extract the `"title"` `(title = "MSI")`? I want the title/brand of the item on the website. I am new to Python. I have only used R and SQL before this instance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the `html` as text not picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a selector path .
Accroding to the img you provided...

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
img = soup.select('.item-brand > img')
print(img['title'])
```

The above should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Try the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="item-branding">
            <a href="https://www.newegg.com/" class="item-brand">
            <img src="https://www.newegg.com/" title="MSI" alt="MSI"> ==$0
            </a></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
element = soup.select('.item-brand > img:nth-of-type(1)')[0]['title']
print(element)
```